# Evitar que se indexe un Custom Post Type y Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, seo

¿Existe alguna forma de que los registros de un post type y una taxonomía no sean indexados por google?

Actualmente tengo un post type y una taxonomía de uso interno que tiene una cantidad de registros que no deseo sean vistos por google o plugins como Yoast SEO y evitar tener una cantidad exagerada de no-index (o evitar no-index en su mayoría).

Cualquier guía se agradece de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlos `no públicos`. Es decir:

- Cuando defines un custom post type  con `register_post_type` tienes que especificar que el argumento `public` a `false`. [Míralo en la página de Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters). Ejemplo:

```php
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Genres', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Genre', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genre:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Genre', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Genre', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Genre', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Genre Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Genre', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'public'            => false,  //<------ públic a false
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'book' ), $args );
```

- Cuando defines una taxonomía pasa lo mismo, esto es, tienes que especificar el parámetro `public` a `false`. [Míralo en la página de Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). Ejempo:

```php
    register_taxonomy(
        'genre',
        'book',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
            'public' => false,  //<------ public a false.
            'rewrite' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
```

Comment: Ah, ya probé y en efecto, hasta se oculta de Yoast SEO, muchas gracias. Seguiré probando para ver como se comporta con google